# How to handle File Associations from Application?

Tags: delphi, file-association

I know Installers can setup File Associations for your Application during the installation process, so if you have your own File types that open with your Application, it will be setup to do that, and also the associated File will have its own icon in Windows what you define.

Anyway, I would like to be able to Set/Remove the File types my Application will use, directly from the preferences form in my Application.

What methods are needed to do this, I am thinking along the lines of the Registry, but then what Keys/Values etc are we to work with, if Registry is the way to go?

Appreciate some advice and tips, It is also important that it works on XP/Vista/7.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: +1 Good idea to do this from a preferences dialog! If ever tempted to "restore" file associations "automagically", please resist the urge. I for one don't much like applications that insist on being the only correct "associate" of a file type, instead of respecting changes by the user the effect of installing another app.

Comment: Noone want to read [sad and lonely reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144104(VS.85).aspx) :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this unit to associate a certain extension to an exe remove the entries made in registry to unregister.

```
unit utils; 

interface 
uses Registry, ShlObj, SysUtils, Windows; 

procedure RegisterFileType(cMyExt, cMyFileType, cMyDescription, ExeName: string; IcoIndex: integer; DoUpdate: boolean = false); 

implementation 

procedure RegisterFileType(cMyExt, cMyFileType, cMyDescription, ExeName: string; IcoIndex: integer; DoUpdate: boolean = false); 
var 
   Reg: TRegistry; 
begin 
  Reg := TRegistry.Create; 
  try 
    Reg.RootKey := HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT; 
    Reg.OpenKey(cMyExt, True); 
    // Write my file type to it. 
    // This adds HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.abc\(Default) = 'Project1.FileType' 
    Reg.WriteString('', cMyFileType); 
    Reg.CloseKey; 
    // Now create an association for that file type 
    Reg.OpenKey(cMyFileType, True); 
    // This adds HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Project1.FileType\(Default) 
    //   = 'Project1 File' 
    // This is what you see in the file type description for 
    // the a file's properties. 
    Reg.WriteString('', cMyDescription); 
    Reg.CloseKey;    // Now write the default icon for my file type 
    // This adds HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Project1.FileType\DefaultIcon 
    //  \(Default) = 'Application Dir\Project1.exe,0' 
    Reg.OpenKey(cMyFileType + '\DefaultIcon', True); 
    Reg.WriteString('', ExeName + ',' + IntToStr(IcoIndex)); 
    Reg.CloseKey; 
    // Now write the open action in explorer 
    Reg.OpenKey(cMyFileType + '\Shell\Open', True); 
    Reg.WriteString('', '&Open'); 
    Reg.CloseKey; 
    // Write what application to open it with 
    // This adds HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Project1.FileType\Shell\Open\Command 
    //  (Default) = '"Application Dir\Project1.exe" "%1"' 
    // Your application must scan the command line parameters 
    // to see what file was passed to it. 
    Reg.OpenKey(cMyFileType + '\Shell\Open\Command', True); 
    Reg.WriteString('', '"' + ExeName + '" "%1"'); 
    Reg.CloseKey; 
    // Finally, we want the Windows Explorer to realize we added 
    // our file type by using the SHChangeNotify API. 
    if DoUpdate then SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, nil, nil); 
  finally 
    Reg.Free; 
  end; 
end; 

end.
```

Registry is defenetly the way to go with things...

Comment: Note that on Vista and Win7 the program will need to be run as Administrator for this to work.

Comment: +1, but is there a way to do this for a specific user only? It would seem to me that using HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT sets it for all users and would require elevation under Vista and up?

Comment: @Nat It requires administrator on NT, Win2000 and WinXP too.

Comment: Negative rating for HKCR use. This old and sloppy code pribably belongs to SiComponents.

Comment: HKCR is actually a view of the result of the merge of HKCU and HKLM \software\classes. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724475(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: "The HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes key corresponds to the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT key, which was retained for compatibility with earlier versions of COM." - https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/win32/com/interface-key

Answer (score 3):

From your app you'd be better to use the per-user store for file associations. If you use the system wide registry location then you'd need to elevate in order to apply changes.  That's not something you should do in a standard user app.

Store the registry settings under:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes
```

The format of entries under there is exactly the same as under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command from your shell
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184082

or 
you can make the entry in registry as shown in the following link
http://www.daycounter.com/LabBook/Changing-File-Associations-With-Registry-Editor.phtml