# Setting up File associations

Tags: delphi

I am trying to get Windows to recognise my program's File extensions but without much luck, as usual.

This is what I am doing, please advise where or what I am doing wrong - I think I might have the registry locations or naming set incorrectly:

**Sample Names**

```
MyProg.exe = The name of the program.
%InstallPath% = Where the program will be installed.
.ext1 = 1st File Extension.
.ext2 = 2nd File Extension.
.ext3 = 3rd File Extension.
```

**Registry Locations (where I have added to)**

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ext1
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ext2
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ext3

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ext1\DefaultIcon,2
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ext1\shell\open\command\%InstallPath%\MyProg.exe %1
```

I got kind of lost off after that :(

**File Images**

I have added the 3 icon files from the XE IDE Resources  Menu, and named them 2,3,4. I think if I have an Icon named 1, it will override the Project icon?

I want to get these working right before using an installer such as Inno Setup on a machine that has never seen my program (to see if the installation was flawless).

I can't find any easy to follow guides :(

Comment: It seems to me you have a pretty easy to follow guide in the accepted answer to your other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704222/how-to-handle-file-associations-from-application). The only thing missing from that is exactly what to provide as the parameters to the procedure call (`cMyFileType` could be `MyProgExt1` in the first instance, `cMyDescription` could be `My Program File Type 1`). Put those values, along with `.ext1` as your extension type, into the code instead of the parameters, and you'll see exactly what you need to do in what order.

Comment: I forgot about that! Well regarding the correct icons, do I just name the resources as I have, such as 2,3,4?

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. The example code from your previous question shows how to deal with the icons as well.

Comment: never mind I've been stupid again, I was following the FAQ for Inno Steup and I was mixing up some of the names. I fixed it in the end :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting up the Registry keys wrong.  You need to associate the file extensions with ProgIDs, then associate the ProgIDs with your app, like this:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ext1 
(Default) = "ext1File"

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ext2 
(Default) = "ext2File"

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ext3 
(Default) = "ext3File"

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ext1File\DefaultIcon
(Default) = "%InstallPath%\MyProg.exe,2" 

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ext1File\shell\open\command
(Default) = ""%InstallPath%\MyProg.exe" "%1""

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ext2File\DefaultIcon
(Default) = "%InstallPath%\MyProg.exe,3" 

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ext2File\shell\open\command
(Default) = ""%InstallPath%\MyProg.exe" "%1""

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ext3File\DefaultIcon
(Default) = "%InstallPath%\MyProg.exe,4" 

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ext3File\shell\open\command
(Default) = ""%InstallPath%\MyProg.exe" "%1""
```

Read the following documentation for more details:

[File Types and File Associations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144104.aspx)

FYI, you should not be writing data to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` directly.  Write to either `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` and/or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` instead, depending on whether you want per-user or machine-global registration.  Read the following documentation for more details as to why.

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475.aspx)

[Merged View of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724498.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the warning, I think I will have an option to install for all users or single user, so for user I would use HKEY_CURRENT_USER Root and for all users HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE root. Thanks Remy