# How to unregister a File Format for my application?

Tags: delphi, registry, file-format, delphi-10.4-sydney

In a Delphi 10.4.2 win-32 VCL Application in Windows 10, I register the `.ICO` file format for my graphics application by using [DSiWin32.DSiRegisterUserFileAssoc](https://github.com/gabr42/OmniThreadLibrary/blob/106ef82fcac01f4f27077acbdefe9c7e057c341e/src/DSiWin32.pas):

```
DSiRegisterUserFileAssoc(
    '.ico',                                              // extension: .ico
    'UGAICOFile',                                        // progID: UGAICOFile
    'ICO File',                                          // description: ICO File
    'C:\DELPHI\MyApp\MyApp.ico',                         // Icon File
    '"C:\DELPHI\MyApp\Win32\Debug\MyApp.exe" "%1"'       // openCommand
    );

SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, nil, nil);
```

This works without problems and when double-clicking an .ICO file in Windows File Explorer my app loads the .ICO file. These Registry keys have been created WITH THE CORRECT VALUES:

[image]

[image]

HOWEVER, when I try to UNREGISTER the `.ICO` file format for my graphics application by using `DSiWin32.DSiUnregisterUserFileAssoc`, it does not work:

```
procedure TForm1.btnUnregisterClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DSiUnregisterUserFileAssoc('UGAICOFile');
  SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, nil, nil);
end;
```

The `UGAICOFile` progID key is not being deleted from the Registry! And double-clicking an .ICO file in File Explorer still loads my app!

Even when I try it in elevated mode (by starting the program as Administrator) it does not work! Could it be that that the Microsoft apps registered under `.ico\OpenWithProgrids` could stop the key from being removed?

So how can I UNREGISTER the registered `.ICO` File Format for my application?

Comment: (1) When you make the association in the first place, please first *ask* the user if that's OK. Maybe the user doesn't want to open icons in your app. (*Many* applications can open icons.) (2) What do you expect should happen when you "unregister"? Should icons then be opened in the app used *before* you registered your app as the handler? Should it not be possible to double-click on icons at all? (Ω) I think you are overthinking this. Just ask before registering, and then just call `Unregister...` when you uninstall your app. Or learn the modern Win 10 details from MSDN.

Comment: I haven't tried the DSi library or changing ICO or Windows 10, but on my Windows 7 system, I can create an association for `.myfile` and then delete it using the naive `TRegistry` approach. It works perfectly. The ProgID key is removed and Explorer cannot any longer open these files by means of double clicking.

Comment: Ah, there's a problem with `DSiUnregisterUserFileAssoc`. Just use the `TRegistry`. No need to add a large library to your app (with all its uncertainties) just for a simple task like this.

Comment: You have to undo the registry operations that are done to register the file. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684027/setting-up-file-associations/8684450#8684450 and remove what is created. Check every operation success!

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Your first comment: (1) That's what I am doing. Why do you think I am not asking the user? (2) The Windows OpenWith dialog appears.

Comment: @ About your second comment: Could it be that that the Microsoft apps registered under .ico\OpenWithProgrids could stop the key from being removed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to be the `DSiUnregisterUserFileAssoc` function not obtaining the required access level to the registry.

One of my rules of thumb when programming is to never use third-party libraries unless absolutely necessary, partly because you don't know all the details about them. And in this case, I don't quite see the point in adding a fairly large library just to do a few simple registry changes!

[Making an association manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285791/how-to-associate-a-program-with-a-file-type-but-only-for-the-current-user/6285850#6285850) is trivial:

```pascal
var Reg := TRegistry.Create;
try
  Reg.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
  if Reg.OpenKey('\Software\Classes\.myfile', True) then
    Reg.WriteString('', 'MyAppDataFile');
  if Reg.OpenKey('\Software\Classes\MyAppDataFile', True) then
    Reg.WriteString('', 'My Very Own Text File Type');
  if Reg.OpenKey('\Software\Classes\MyAppDataFile\DefaultIcon', True) then
    Reg.WriteString('', 'C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe');
  if Reg.OpenKey('\Software\Classes\MyAppDataFile\shell\open\command', True) then
    Reg.WriteString('', 'C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe "%1"');
finally
  Reg.Free;
end;
SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, nil, nil);
```

And so is removing it:

```pascal
var Reg := TRegistry.Create;
try
  Reg.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
  Reg.DeleteKey('\Software\Classes\MyAppDataFile');
finally
  Reg.Free;
end;
SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, nil, nil);
```

This works, it requires no additional library (with a lot of things you don't need, potential security issues, potential bugs, etc.), and you know exactly what the code does. You have 100% understanding of it.

---

I was able to make the DSi function work by changing it to this:

```
DSiKillRegistry('\Software\Classes\' + progID, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, KEY_ALL_ACCESS);
```

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Your code to unregister works. Now double-clicked .ICO files open in Microsoft Sketch app (which is one of the apps in the existing key `.ico\OpenWithProgrids`). I should file file a bug issue in the DSIWin32 Github repository.

Comment: Done: Issue filed. I mentioned you as the one who found the bug.

Comment: You should replace "MyAppDataFile" with something that makes it clear that this is an IDENTIFIER to avoid confusion. Give it a better name like `AFileFormatID`.

Comment: @user1580348: I don't think that makes it any more clear.

Comment: `AFileFormatID` starts with the letter 'A' which is a common prefix for parameters. The postfix 'ID' makes it clear this is a parameter to identify something. The words 'FileFormat' tell the purpose of the identifier.

Comment: @user1580348: But `'MyAppDataFile'` is a string literal, and not a parameter! :) (And just to be crystal clear: The `A` prefix for parameters stands for "argument" (cf `F` for "field", `T` for "type", `I` for "interface", `E` for "exception" etc.), and not the English article.)

Comment: Anyhow, this Q isn't about how to make a file association (a Q that has been asked hundreds of thousands of times since the introduction of Windows 95 some 26 years ago), it's about the problem with the DSi library function for unregistering. I have added a link to one of those Qs. That Q defines all file type parameters and the extension, which only leaves the "ID", the function of which is rather obvious from the structure of the registry additions, and the "MyAppDataFile" is easily seen to be a placeholder (unless "MyApp" happens to be the name of an actual app!).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand "The A prefix for parameters stands for argument". That's why you should package your code inside a procedure or function. Then a parameter like `AFileFormatID` would make sense.

Comment: @user1580348: Yes, of course you should place this code in a function. That goes without saying.

Comment: But even if you should put this code in a nice function when you use it in your application, I do think it is perfectly OK for me not to do so in this answer, because before you begin to use such a neatly packaged function you must understand fully how it works. My code snippet should help you understand what to do in the registry, and then it is up to you to do this in a best-practices kind of way in your own code. Also, regarding examples vs technical specifications, different people have different preferences when it comes to their way of learning and understanding. Personally, I am ...

Comment: ... generally a big fan of fully precise, technical definitions and specifications, but many people prefer examples and most people benefit from a combination. I do think a fair amount of readers would find this example code easy to mentally parse and generalise.

Comment: I personally think the term "MyAppDataFile" contributes to confusion.